# How to open safari settings from safari mobile browser programmatically

Tags: ios, safari

I tried opening safari settings from Safari web browser.
I used:

`window.location.href = "prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Camera"`

I get an error telling Safari cannot open because it is an invalid path.
How to open safari website settings from safari browser programmatically?